# "All the inputs are not current" after Precondition = false in Model Builder

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, modelbuilder

I am using an Iterator to Iterate through a list of Strings for Feature Selection/Aggregation/Count. There is the possibility that no Features are aggregated. In this case, I want the iterator to go to the next %String%. However, in such a situation, the model runs as follows:

- Executing (Iterate Field Values): IterateFieldValues ...
- Succeeded ...
- Executing (Select): Select ... Data.shp in_memory\TagFeaturesSelect ... LIKE '%;seo;%' - ...
- Executing (Get Count): GetCount in_memory\TagFeaturesSelect
- Row Count = 11
- Executing (Calculate Value): CalculateValue check(11) "def check(rowcount)... Boolean
- Value = true
- ...
- Executing (Aggregate Points): AggregatePoints in_memory\TagFeaturesSelect ...
- Finding point clusters...
- Constructing polygons...
- ...
- Executing (Get Count 2): GetCount C:\01_TOOLS\Intermediate\SelTaglocationsAgg.shp
- Row Count = 0
- **The process did not execute because the precondition is false.**
- Succeeded at ...
- **Executing (Spatial Join)**: SpatialJoin ...\SelTaglocationsAgg.shp in_memory\TagFeaturesSelect ...\output_seo.shp ...
- Start Time: ...
- **All the inputs are not current.**
- Succeeded at ...
- Executing (Spatial Join (3)): ...
- Start Time: ...
- All the inputs are not current.
- Succeeded at ...
- Executing (Summary Statistics): ...
- Start Time: ...
- All the inputs are not current.
- Succeeded at ...
  ...

This is the Model I am talking about:
[image: Model Diagram]

I also tried using Calculate Value with result = false for Row Count = 0, but the same result. The Model also ignores whether I set [Row Count 2] as a precondition for [Spatial Join (3)] or not.
My model still continues, but I get all the errors and I believe, this is not by intention?

Comment: Try setting that Row Count or the Calculate Value as prerequisite for every operation that follows after the one it is the prerequisite for.

Comment: Hi Curran, I will give this a try soon, thanks for your answer!